# heroku: run this app correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am recently using the rubymine(ruby on rails 4) to create web pages and once I have finished some functions and run correctly,I push my code to heroku, so I can directly run the app on the heroku.

The problem is that every function could run correctly on the heroku just like running it at local except one: There is a link in one page called "calendar" to a calendar function,I can run it correctly at local, but on heroku, it goes wrong saying "we are sorry but something went wrong"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAkrd.jpg)

someone can explain to me how could it happen? Is it a bug of the heroku system, like a compatibility issue? I have push my code to heroku and run correctly many times and it won't be wrong in the push process.

here is my heroku link: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/clients-to-horse

Comment: Something is broken there, use `heroku logs` to see what do log say or `heroku logs -n 1500` to see a more complete log.

Comment: You can add Papertrail add-ons to your Heroku project to show your log

Answer (score 0):

## Sugession

I will recommend you, please run your application on local in production mode(environment) after assets precompile, if everything will work properly then I am sure on Heroku will run also.

After deploy on Heroku make sure for migration and assets precompile for Heroku.

You are saying error as "we are sorry but something went wrong", this always comes when we miss something from our side or code bug in the application.